# How can I extract a resource into a file at runtime?

Tags: delphi, embedded-resource, extract

I want to distribute only a single .exe, however, at runtime I would like it to extract some embedded image resources to the users hard disk drive.

Can I, and if so, how?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use Delphi's TResourceStream. It's constructor will find and load the resource into memory, and it's SaveToFile method will do the disk write.

Something similar to this should work:

```
var
  ResStream: TResourceStream;
begin
  ResStream := TResourceStream.Create(HInstance, 'YOURRESOURCENAME', RT_RCDATA);
  try
    ResStream.Position := 0;
    ResStream.SaveToFile('C:\YourDir\YourFileName.jpg');
  finally
    ResStream.Free;
  end;
end;
```

If you can use the resource ID instead of name, it's a little less memory. In that case, you'd resplace Create with CreateFromID, and supply the numeric ID rather than the string name.

Comment: Whatever value the OS tells you, @Leonix. `HInstance` is a global variable that Delphi initializes for you as your program starts up. It's in the *SysInit* unit.

Answer (score 4):

Create a [`TResourceStream`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/XE/en/Classes.TResourceStream). You'll need the module instance handle (usually `SysInit.HInstance` for the current EXE file, or else whatever you get from `LoadLibrary` or `LoadPackage`), the resource type (such as `rt_Bitmap` or `rt_RCData`), and either the resource name or numeric ID. Then call the stream's [`SaveToFile`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/XE/en/Classes.TCustomMemoryStream.SaveToFile) method.

Answer (score 2):

```
try
   if not Assigned(Bitmap)
   then
      Bitmap := TBitmap.Create();
   Bitmap.LoadFromResourceName(HInstance,SRC);
except
   on E:Exception do
      ShowMessage(e.Message);
end;
```

And then save the Bitmap to disk.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this might come in handy too if you need to work with the resources itself.
[Delphidabbler / ResourceFiles](http://www.delphidabbler.com/software/resfile?mid=3.2)