# Extract the resource file

Tags: delphi, resources, extract

I have attached a resource file to an existing `exe` file using `UpdateResource` function.

How can I extract it?

**Edit**

This is my code to attach a resource file to an existing exe file :

```
Uses Classes, Windows, SysUtils, Dialogs;

Type
  TBuffer = Array[0..0] of Byte;
  PBuffer = ^TBuffer;

Var
  FS             : TFileStream;
  ResourceHandle : THandle;
  DataLength     : DWord;
  Data           : PBuffer;
  Ok             : Boolean;

Begin
   ResourceHandle := BeginUpdateResource(pChar('d:\someexefile.exe'), False);
   IF (ResourceHandle <> 0) Then
   Begin
      FS := TFileStream.Create('d:\somebitmap.bmp', fmOpenRead);
      FS.Seek(0, soFromBeginning);
      DataLength := FS.Size;
      GetMem(Data, DataLength);
      FS.Read(Data^, DataLength);
      FS.Free;

      Ok := True;
      IF (not UpdateResource(ResourceHandle, RT_RCDATA, pChar('MyNewResource'), LANG_SYSTEM_DEFAULT{MakeLangID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_NEUTRAL)}, Data, DataLength)) Then Ok := False;

      IF (not EndUpdateResource(ResourceHandle, False)) Then Ok := False;

      IF (Ok) Then ShowMessage('Update of resources successful!')
         Else ShowMessage('Update of resources failed!');

      FreeMem(Data);
   End;
End.
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `LoadLibraryEx` passing `LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_IMAGE_
RESOURCE` to load the module and then `TResourceStream.SaveToFile` to save the resource.

I am of course assuming that you don't want to extract the resource from the running executable. If that were the case you could go straight to `TResourceStream.SaveToFile`.

Comment: I've also used `TResourceStream.SaveToFile`. but doesn't work and this error will be shown : `Resource [MyResName] not found.`

Comment: And you were calling it from within the executable itself? In that case your code simply contains a bug, and _that_ is the code you should post.

Comment: most likely you got the HMODULE, resource name or resource type wrong.

Comment: My code to extract the resource : `ResStream := TResourceStream.Create(HInstance, 'MyNewResource', RT_RCDATA);`

Comment: you'll need to use `LoadLibrary(PChar('d: \someexefile.exe'))` to get the right module instance as per my answer. Your code currently looks for the resource in your update/extract module rather than the exe you are modifying.

Comment: `hMod := LoadLibrary(PChar ('d: \someexefile.exe'))` and then pass hMod rather than HInstance.

Comment: Does not work ! `var
  ResStream: TResourceStream;
  hMod: Cardinal;
begin
  hMod := LoadLibrary(PChar(ExtractFilePath(application.ExeName)));
  ResStream := TResourceStream.Create(hMod, 'FPM_OPT', RT_RCDATA);
  try
    ResStream.SaveToFile('c:\1.txt');
  finally
    ResStream.Free;
  end;`

Comment: That's equivalent to using HInstance. Is the resource in the executable in which this code lives, or some other executable? I'm finding it hard to work out what you have done wrong with so little clear detail.

Comment: David , I found the problem. `lptype` was incorrect. Thank you so much :)

Comment: good. If the resource is in the running executable then just use HInstance. No need for LoadLibrary in that case.

Answer (score 3):

there are several tools you can use:

[XN Resource Explorer](http://delphi.about.com/od/fullcodeprojects/ss/xnresourceedit.htm)

[Resource Hacker](http://delphi.about.com/gi/o.htm?zi=1/XL&zTi=1&sdn=delphi&cdn=compute&tm=75&f=22&su=p284.9.336.ip_p504.1.336.ip_&tt=3&bt=0&bts=0&zu=http://www.users.on.net/johnson/resourcehacker/)

[Resource-Grabber](http://delphi.about.com/gi/o.htm?zi=1/XL&zTi=1&sdn=delphi&cdn=compute&tm=85&f=22&su=p284.9.336.ip_p504.1.336.ip_&tt=3&bt=0&bts=0&zu=http://inner-smile.com/dl_res.htm)

from code by using [DelphiDabbler](http://www.delphidabbler.com/software/resfile?mid=3.2).

or by using `TResourceStream` class. this question explain you how to use it: [How can I extract a resource into a file at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3684465/how-can-i-extract-a-resource-into-a-file-at-run-time)